# How to generate a vagrant file to replicate an existing (non-vagrant) VirtualBox running Debian?

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, vagrant

I have a VirtualBox VM, created "by hand" (i.e., without using vagrant at all), which runs Debian.

What is the simplest way to generate a vagrant file that would replicate this box?  Is there an automated way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "replicate"? If you mean recreating from bare Debian and installing all packages, then you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Did you already tried what suggested [here](https://github.com/crohr/ebarnouflant/issues/7)? In this way you can _Convert a VirtualBox .ova VM into a Vagrant box_ then from there you can duplicate/clone... If that was you goal let me know that I will write one answer with some words more...

Comment: The automated way/procedures (eventually existent) may depend on the host OS. Which is yours?

Comment: @Hastur: my host is also Debian.

Comment: @kjo thx. BTW I found [vagrantmanager](http://vagrantmanager.com/) but unfortunately is not for Linux...

Answer (score 2):

You can try following the steps reported in the github page ["Convert a VirtualBox `.ova` VM into a Vagrant `box` #7"](https://github.com/crohr/ebarnouflant/issues/7), skipping the first one because you already have your VM (and you are not starting from an `ova` file)...

1. Individuate the internal name, ID, reading it from the GUI or by commandline with the `VBoxManage` command:

   > VBoxManage list vms
   >   "UCS 4.1" {**acef4c0a-35be-4640-a214-be135417f011**}

   You are interested in **`acef4c0a-35be-4640-a214-be135417f011`**, that on your computer will be different (instead of UCS 4.1 you have to select the VM name you given to your debian system).
2. *Package* that VM as a Vagrant box

   > vagrant package --base **acef4c0a-35be-4640-a214-be135417f011** --output **UCS.box**

   Take the unique ID found before and write instead of **`acef4c0a-35be-4640-a214-be135417f011`** in the above command line. Note that you can change the output filename as you want (instead of `UCS.box` you can use `whatever.box`), but you will need to use the same name in the next command.
3. Add to the list of your local Vagrant boxes

   > vagrant box add **UCS.box** --name **UCS**

   With the file name chosen before you can add the box to `vagrant`, choosing even the *human readable* name (in the above case UCS). The name has to be reported in the next file.
4. Create a [Vagrantfile](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/) to use this box, or modify one you already have:

   > Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   >    config.vm.box = "**UCS**"
   >    # ...
   >   end
5. `vagrant up`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any *.ova files in my vms directory, so I think this may not work for me.

Comment: You're welcome. You have not to see any ova file (it's the analogous of a zip file or cab...).  Enter in a shell (DOS prompt or Linux Bash Shell if you are under windows 10)  and write the command in the point 1 `VBoxManage list vms`. It will answer with the list of the __already__ present VM. Take the strange number (acef4c0a...) associated with the "human readable" one (it will be different on your computer... then continue to use the other commands...   You can change the names but you have to change even in the next step (see the bold part to understand better).

Comment: Add `config.ssh.insert_key = false` and follow this answer to remove ssh problems: ["Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying... " after packaging box](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/5186#issuecomment-77681605)